# Can you search for businesses near you matching a particular list of businesses using Google Places API?

Tags: android, ios, google-places-api

Say I have a list of businesses in a Google App Engine Datastore.

Is it possible to use Google Maps Api to display for example the 10 closest businesses listed in the datastore to an Android or iOS device's GPS coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@swanhella..

Use Below Code Code for **IOS TO FING NEARBY PLACES USING Google API with Images**
You have to First Register for Google Api Console .,..

Download Library Which is Used

1. [FTGooglePlacesAPI](https://github.com/FuerteInternational/FTGooglePlacesAPI)
2. [AFNetworking Library](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)
3. [SDWebimage Library](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

1.first Set in **AppDelegate**.. //Key YOu can got from Google API At the time of Registration with Bundle Identifier

```
#import "FTGooglePlacesAPI.h"

    [FTGooglePlacesAPIService provideAPIKey:@"AIzaSyA1B4sNPcKPf76dcgLgYsJzCVP79NRTUKI"];
```

2.then in you Controller ..**Import** below Library

```
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "FTGooglePlacesAPI.h"
#import "FTGooglePlacesAPIExampleDetailViewController.h"
#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, FTGooglePlacesAPIExampleType) {
    FTGooglePlacesAPIExampleTypeMuseumKeyword,
};

@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D locationCoordinate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<FTGooglePlacesAPIRequest> initialRequest;
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<FTGooglePlacesAPIRequest> actualRequest;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation *searchLocation;
@property (nonatomic, strong) FTGooglePlacesAPISearchResponse *lastResponse;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicatorView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *results;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
// Custom initialization
    //Here i have Set Custom Location
    self.locationCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(23.0370544,72.5142021);

    //Clear Data
    _results = [NSMutableArray array];

    _searchLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:self.locationCoordinate.latitude longitude:self.locationCoordinate.longitude];

    //Set Activity Indicator
    self.activityIndicatorView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    _activityIndicatorView.hidesWhenStopped = YES;

    UIBarButtonItem *activityBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:_activityIndicatorView];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = activityBarButton;

    //Create Request to Get Data from Google Places
    id<FTGooglePlacesAPIRequest> request = [self googlePlacesAPIRequestForExampleType:FTGooglePlacesAPIExampleTypeMuseumKeyword];

    _initialRequest = request;
    _actualRequest = request;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    //  Controller is first displayed - start searching
    if ([_results count] == 0) {
        [self startSearching];
    }
}

#pragma mark - FTGooglePlacesAPI performing search request

- (void)startSearching
{
    //  Show activity indicator
    [_activityIndicatorView startAnimating];

    //  Execute Google Places API request using FTGooglePlacesAPIService
    [FTGooglePlacesAPIService executeSearchRequest:_actualRequest
                             withCompletionHandler:^(FTGooglePlacesAPISearchResponse *response, NSError *error)
     {
         //  If error is not nil, request failed and you should handle the error
         //  We just show alert
         if (error)
         {
             //  There may be a lot of causes for an error (for example networking error).
             //  If the network communication with Google Places API was successfull,
             //  but the API returned some status code, NSError will have
             //  FTGooglePlacesAPIErrorDomain domain and status code from
             //  FTGooglePlacesAPIResponseStatus enum
             //  You can inspect error's domain and status code for more detailed info

             UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[error localizedDescription] message:[error localizedFailureReason] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [alert show];
             [_activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
             return;
         }

         //  Everything went fine, we have response object
         //  You can do whatever you need here, we just add new items to the
         //  data source array and reload the table
         //  You could add new rows with animation etc., but it would add useless
         //  complexity to the sample code app

         //  Update last response object
         _lastResponse = response;

         //  Add new results to the data source array
         [_results addObjectsFromArray:response.results];

         //         NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"description" ascending:YES selector:@selector(compare:)];



         //These Distance Code may be useful to SORT in Future....
         for (int i=0; i<[_results count]; i++)
         {
             //  Get response object
             FTGooglePlacesAPISearchResultItem *resultItem = _results[i];

             if (resultItem.location) {
                 CLLocationDistance distance = [resultItem.location distanceFromLocation:_searchLocation];
                 NSString *strdistance = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance: %.0fm", distance];
                 NSLog(@"strdistance=%@",strdistance);
                 resultItem.strDistance=strdistance;
             }
         }

         [self.tblMain reloadData];

         [_activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
     }];
}

- (id<FTGooglePlacesAPIRequest>)googlePlacesAPIRequestForExampleType:(FTGooglePlacesAPIExampleType)type
{
    id<FTGooglePlacesAPIRequest> result;

    switch (type)
    {
        case FTGooglePlacesAPIExampleTypeMuseumKeyword:
        {
            **FTGooglePlacesAPINearbySearchRequest *request = [[FTGooglePlacesAPINearbySearchRequest alloc] initWithLocationCoordinate:self.locationCoordinate];
            //  may be useful in future
            //  FTGooglePlacesAPITextSearchRequest *request = [[FTGooglePlacesAPITextSearchRequest alloc] initWithQuery:@"pizza in london"];

            //Diff types of sort in Google Places
            //  request.keyword = @"museum";
            //  request.openNow = YES;
            //  request.types = @[@"art_gallery", @"museum"];
            //  request.types = @[@"restaurant"];
            //  request.minPrice = 4;

            request.radius = 500;
            result = request;**
        }
            break;
    }
    return result;
}

#pragma mark Table view Method

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;    //count of section
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

//    return ArrList.count;    //count number of row from counting array hear cataGorry is An Array
    return [_results count] + ([_lastResponse hasNextPage]);

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    //Load More Cell
    static NSString *LoadMoreCellIdentifier = @"LoadMoreCell";
    //Custom Design Cell
    static NSString *ResultCellIdentifier = @"CELL_Custom";

    BOOL isLoadMoreResultsCell = [self isLoadMoreResultsCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *cellIdentifier = (isLoadMoreResultsCell? LoadMoreCellIdentifier:ResultCellIdentifier);

    // Using Custom Cell
    CELL_Custom *cell=(CELL_Custom *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    //  Configure "Load more" cell
    if (isLoadMoreResultsCell)
    {
        //  This is constant cell, so we can preconfigure it on the init
        if (cell==nil)
        {
            NSArray *nibs=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CELL_Custom"
                                                        owner:self options:nil];
            cell=[nibs objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        cell.Lbl_Name.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        cell.Lbl_Name.text = @"Load more results...";
        [cell.Lbl_Name setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.Lbl_Name.frame.origin.x-70, cell.Lbl_Name.frame.origin.y, cell.Lbl_Name.frame.size.width+70, cell.Lbl_Name.frame.size.height)];
        [cell.Lbl_Name setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:30]];
        [cell.Img_thumb setHidden:YES];
        [cell.Lbl_sec setHidden:YES];
        return cell;
    }
    else   //  Configure "CELL_Custom" cell
    {
        if (cell==nil)
        {
            NSArray *nibs=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CELL_Custom"
                                                        owner:self options:nil];
            cell=[nibs objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.Img_thumb setHidden:NO];
        [cell.Lbl_sec setHidden:NO];
        cell.Img_thumb.layer.cornerRadius = cell.Img_thumb.frame.size.width/2;
        cell.Img_thumb.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

        //  Get response object
        FTGooglePlacesAPISearchResultItem *resultItem = _results[indexPath.row];

        cell.Lbl_Name.text=resultItem.name;

        NSLog(@"resultItem.strDistance=%@",resultItem.strDistance);
        if (resultItem.location) {
            CLLocationDistance distance = [resultItem.location distanceFromLocation:_searchLocation];
            cell.Lbl_sec.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance: %.0fm", distance];
        }

        //if temp Set Icon to Image
        [cell.Img_thumb setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:resultItem.iconImageUrl] placeholderImage:[self placeholderImage]];

        //If Place found Photos
        if(resultItem.photos !=nil)
        {
            NSArray *aryPhotos = resultItem.photos;
            NSString *photoreference =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[aryPhotos objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"photo_reference"]];

            //Save Temp in SDImageCache
            if ([[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] imageFromDiskCacheForKey:photoreference])
            {
                cell.Img_thumb.image=[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] imageFromDiskCacheForKey:photoreference];
            }
            else
            {
                NSString *strPlace=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=%@&key=%@",photoreference,@"AIzaSyA1B4sNPcKPf76dcgLgYsJzCVP79NRTUKI"];
                NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:strPlace];
                NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
                [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
                 {
                     UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithData:data];

                     [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] storeImage:img forKey:photoreference];
                     cell.Img_thumb.image=[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] imageFromDiskCacheForKey:photoreference];
                 }];
            }
        }
        return cell;
    }
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 80;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    //  Selected "Load more results" cell
    if ([self isLoadMoreResultsCellAtIndexPath:indexPath])
    {
        //  Get request for a new page of results and start search
        id<FTGooglePlacesAPIRequest> nextPageRequest = [_lastResponse nextPageRequest];
        _actualRequest = nextPageRequest;
        [self startSearching];
    }
    //  Selected result item cell
    else
    {
        //  Get response object
        FTGooglePlacesAPISearchResultItem *resultItem = _results[indexPath.row];

        //  Create detail request
        FTGooglePlacesAPIDetailRequest *request = [[FTGooglePlacesAPIDetailRequest alloc] initWithPlaceId:resultItem.placeId];

        //  Create detail controller
        FTGooglePlacesAPIExampleDetailViewController *detailController = [[FTGooglePlacesAPIExampleDetailViewController alloc] initWithRequest:request];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailController animated:YES];

        //  And print it to the console
        NSLog(@"Selected item: %@", resultItem);
    }
}

- (UIImage *)placeholderImage
{
    static UIImage *PlaceholderImage;

    if (!PlaceholderImage)
    {
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40.0f, 40.0f);

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
        [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
        [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:rect] fill];
        PlaceholderImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }

    return PlaceholderImage;
}

#pragma mark - LoadMore methods

- (BOOL)isLoadMoreResultsCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //  It is load more cell if there is more results to read and this is
    //  the last cell in a table view
    NSInteger numberOfRows = [self tableView:self.tblMain numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section];
    return ((indexPath.row == numberOfRows - 1) && [_lastResponse hasNextPage]);
}
```

//***happy Coding..***

Comment: Thanks for the response. However I'm looking if I can search for only specific businesses near me. This looks like it gets all businesses, correct? If I have 10,000 businesses stored in a Google datastore, I want to know if there's a way to search for the nearest businesses without having to download details of ALL of them and THEN sorting by distance to find which ones are near me. It's not a very scalable option. Thank you very much.

Comment: @swanhella, U have to set -> request.radius = 500; 
SO in this way you can gets all near me  businesses in that Radius...
& second thing is that You have to Manually Sort Them. Response u got is all nearest businesses in Range of Radius u Specify.

Comment: @swanhella.. best of luck.. keep trying

Comment: So far so good. It's a shame FTGooglePlacesAPI does not support the Place Photos API

Comment: @swanhellam, is my code it helpful to you, i have Simply Added Photo Features in Library.

Comment: unfortunately `resultItem.photos` does not work. The search result item doesn't support it - [here](https://github.com/FuerteInternational/FTGooglePlacesAPI/blob/master/FTGooglePlacesAPI/FTGooglePlacesAPISearchResultItem.h). I actually got it working today parsing it manually using `resultItem.originalDictionaryRepresentation`. Somebody made a pull request on GitHub including support for photo search but the author hasn't accepted it yet. I'm using cocoa pods so I don't want to mess with it.